# CMake: build lib and link it to executable results in undefined reference error

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I have a cmake setup that is supposed to first build a library and then use this library to create an executable:

```
# build and install the project lib
add_library(lib${PROJECT_NAME} 
    test.cpp
)
install(TARGETS lib${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DIR})
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ DESTINATION ${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR} FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h*")


# link lib and create executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lib${PROJECT_NAME})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DIR})
```

The lib building part works, but it seems the linking of the lib does not. I am using a simple add method which is implemented in the test.cpp and I get an undefined reference to this method.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The first argument to your `target_link_libraries` call must be the name of the executable target, i.e. `${PROJECT_NAME}`, the second is the library target.

Comment: Yes, that's it, should read the documentation next time more carefully next time.... thanks. You can put it in an answer and will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to a `target_link_libraries` call has to be the name of the target the library should be linked to, i.e. `${PROJECT_NAME}` in your case, the second argument is the library target. See documentation for [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries).

In your example you need to use: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} lib${PROJECT_NAME})`